# Access filter won't show value list to choose from after 1st filter is set

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm having a little trouble with the form filter in Access 2007. I'm using the listview in a few forms and the user needs to be able to filter there.

For testing purposes I made a query, which is just based on one table. If I want to set the first filter, it looks like that:

[image: Normal filter]

I choose a value and if I want to set another filter (on a different field obviously), there aren't values available to choose from.

[image: 2nd filter]

This seems to happen only if I use a query (doesn't matter if I use every field, or just a few, based on one table or multiple linked tables). I can of course use the number filter and enter a value manually.

I have another database, where I can use filters when and wherever I want, regardless whether it is a query or a table - I have a list with values to choose from everytime. This means I messed something somewhere up but I have absolutely no clue where.

I'm using Access 2007 (FE/BE), if you need any further details, just ask. Any advice where to start looking is very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after playing around for a long while, I figured out what the problem is.

The form recordsource needs to be a query - no sql code, no "select * from query", just the name of a query. Anything else leads to the fact that you are limited in using the filters. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is a reason behind this, but that's the way it works in access 2007 - at least for me.

Before I was dynamically adding conditions to my queries which led to a recordsource like "select * from qDeliveries where location = 1". To accomplish this I now just create a temporary query which is the form recordsource instead of just using the sql code.

Hope this helps anyone... :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a query, try this:

1. **File** >> **Options**
2. **Current Database**
3. Scroll down to **Filter lookup options**
4. Check **ODBC Fields**

Close and re-open the file. That should solve the issue.

Comment: This totally worked. Saved my day Asad, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Separate query and assign to that form. instead of create query within the form. Your problem might get resolved. I did the same way it's working fine for me.