# MS-Access filter lookup option for ODBC linked table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a SQL Server table linked in MS-Access 2016.

The filter lookup options for fields in this table are not appearing, as expected:

[image: screenshot showing only options to sort & search].

I have set the Database Options to allow Filter Lookup for ODBC fields, putting the max records to 1M (not necessary - there are <500K in the largest table), to no avail.

[image: Access Database Options showing ODBC Fields checked].

I've Compacted, I've closed Access and re-opened, the fields are `nvarchar(255)`.

I'm out of ideas. Does anybody have any?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying this occurs for some columns, or for all columns? The filter in your screen capture does seem to look ok - you just not clicked on the sub menu filter to see more options. I also noted that for large (memo) type of fields, you don't get as many options.  You could open up the linked table in design view, and see if the columns are seen as text or memo columns.

Comment: It doesn't provide the checkboxes for filtering only for the columns that use a Lookup from another table/view.  That is a clue, perhaps - this is a bridge table of ID's from 2 SQL Server tables, and I use a Lookup Query for a Combo Box in the datasheet to show the names, rather than the ID values.  But the column that just uses a Value List Combo Box (Priority) works as expected.  I've had this same set up work numerous times before with different databases.  Don't know why it doesn't work now.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I checked the structure of the linked tables (Subjects and Collections) and the name fields are both seen as Short Text (255).  So I don't think that's the issue.  Good thing to check, though.  Thanks.

Comment: Interestingly, I checked my other databases, which have used the same set-up (linking to SQL Server tables, using Lookup queries for easier data entry).   Previously, I could use the Quick Filter option, and it would display the options in a checkbox format for, well, quick filtering.  Now, the checkbox list in Quick Filter no longer appears for any of the linked tables that use Lookup Queries.  It must have something to do with the format of the Lookup Queries - I checked this and nothing looks extraordinary - how can I post an image with a comment?  Still searching...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the answer after doing more digging in Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10949856/13282028 .  Turns out that the checkboxes would only appear if I reference a saved query in the Lookup settings, rather than using a SELECT query.

This screenshot shows what *doesn't* work:
[Lookup settings using a SELECT query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1moJE.png).

This screenshot shows what **does** work:
[Lookup settings referencing a saved query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oH1zp.png)

All is well, but I wanted to share this to make it easier for folks in the future to find this answer.